# renderAll function does not invoke

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

**Scenario**

I am making app using backbonejs, requirejs and jquery. I am retrieving data from remote server. Once the data is fetched, then I want to display it to the user.

**Problem**

First I fetch data inside `app.js` file then I make a instance of `MoviesView` and pass `collection` in to this view. Inside `MoviesView`, I have `initialize` function and inside this function I am listening to an `Event triggered` by `router`. Once that event is listened then it should call `renderAll` function. **The problem lies here, it does not invoke `renderAll` function at all.**

**My code**

here is function where I am fetching data from the server

```
fetchBoxOfficeMovies: function () {
        var movieCollection = new MoviesCollection;

        movieCollection.fetch({success: this.successCallback, error: this.errorCallback}).then(function () {
            //console.log(movieCollection.toJSON());
            new MoviesView({ collection: movieCollection });
        });
    },

    successCallback: function () {
        console.log('successCallback');
    },
```

Here is the `router` where I am triggering an event

```
routes: {
        '': 'index'
    },

    index: function () {
        App.Vent.trigger('init');
        console.log('router');
    }
```

And here is `initialize and renderAll` functions inside MoviesView

```
initialize: function () {
        App.Vent.on('init', this.renderAll, this);
        console.log('movies view');
    },

    renderAll: function () {
        console.log('renderAll');
    },
```

**Output which I see in my console**

Here is what I see in my console

```
router 
successCallback 
movies view
```

**As you can see I do not see *renderAll* in my console.**

**Question**

**Why don't I see *renderAll* and how can I fix this?**

**UPDATE**

Here is my entire App view

```
var App = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'body',

    initialize: function () {
        App.router = new MainRouter();
        Backbone.history.start();

        this.fetchBoxOfficeMovies();
    },

    fetchBoxOfficeMovies: function () {
        var movieCollection = new MoviesCollection;

        movieCollection.fetch({success: this.successCallback, error: this.errorCallback}).then(function () {
            //console.log(movieCollection.toJSON());
            new MoviesView({ collection: movieCollection });
        });
    },

    successCallback: function () {
        console.log('successCallback');
    },

    errorCallback: function () {
        console.log('errorCallback');
    }

});
```

As it can be seen that I am making new instance of `MainRouter` before calling `fetchBoxOfficeMovies`, which means I am triggering event before everything else.

Comment: Looks like you are binding an event handler *after* the event has occurred.

Comment: How? Could you elaborate? please

Comment: First I see `router` in my console then after few seconds `successCallback` and `movies view` appears respectively. Which I think means is the correct order of displaying, thus correct order of binding an event. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: "Attention everyone, an event called `init` has just happened". *<a few seconds pass>* "Hey, if an event called `init` happens, let me know." *<nothing happens>* -- Your event handler registration happens long after the event you're binding to, do you expect it to "go back in time" and replay the original event?

Comment: Could you please tell me where should I register Event so that it works? Sorry I new to backbone that why I am asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

As DCoder said, you got the order wrong. Rename your console.log to understand better what's happening.

```
router                 -> I trigger a 'init' event
successCallback        -> successCallback
movies view            -> I start listening 'init' events NOW
```

Suggested 'Fix':

```
movieCollection.fetch({
    success: this.successCallback, 
    error: this.errorCallback
}).then(function () {
    //console.log(movieCollection.toJSON());
    var moviesView = new MoviesView({ collection: movieCollection });
    moviesView.renderAll()
});
```

Comment: This solution does not use router. I want to use router so that my back button works.